# An axiom that shows that the real numbers are weakly countable?

Tags: topos-theory, constructive-mathematics, reverse-math

Is there a model of Intuitionistic Higher-Order Logic in which the following axiom is true?

**Covering Axiom**: *Any true statement of the form $\forall x \in A, \exists y \in B, \phi(x,y)$ gives rise to an open covering of $A$, and a continuous mapping from each set in the covering to $B$, such that $\phi(x,f(x))$ is true.*

I understand that there are difficulties finding "nice enough" categories of topological spaces that behaves like toposes.

The motivation for the axiom above is that it contradicts Weak Countable Choice, and seems to suggest that the set $[0,1]\subset\mathbb R$ may be "weakly countable" under it. By weakly countable, I mean the negation of uncountable.

It isn't shown below, but I have a way of extending the argument from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R$.

[image]

Comment: The axiom feels like it's missing half a sentence. Is there any supposed relation between the $\forall\exists$ statement and the continuous functions? Perhaps that the pair $(a,f(a))$ satisfies the statement?

Comment: @Wojowu Any true statement of the form $\forall x \in A, \exists y \in B, \phi(x,y)$ gives rise to an open covering of $A$, and a continuous mapping from each set in the covering to $B$, such that $\phi(x,f(x))$ is true. I'm not sure if that's clearer...

Comment: It definitely is clearer, since now you indicate the relation between the two!

Comment: @Wojowu I've added the clarification

Comment: A good place to look is Michael Beeson’s Foundations of Constructive Mathematics, ch XVI.

Comment: It's known that the reals are "weakly countable" in the topos of sheaves over the real numbers (see the appendix of http://www.cs.au.dk/~spitters/obs.pdf ). I imagine an argument similar to the one you gave works in the internal logic, but there are a few things to check. E.g. defining compact in terms of finite subcovers is usually too strong constructively and countable products of compact spaces aren't always compact. Also, the statement of the covering axiom seems very strong because it's stated for arbitrary topological spaces.

Comment: @aws Thanks. This is good to know

Comment: What are the quantifiers on $A$ and $B$? Are they arbitrary topological spaces?